# Proportion of objects meeting condition based on distributions of attributes

Tags: conditional-probability, proportion

There is a population of objects where each object has two independent attributes, each of these attributes being continuous and having normal distribution (known).
Is there a general way to infer what proportion of these objects will fulfill a condition which is given by a simple function between these attributes? 
X(mx,sx)
Y(my,sy)
Example of a function in my case: Y>1/X+c

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: this appears to be a homework question...please consider the self-study tag

Comment: Trying to develop analytical method measuring x and y (being attributes of chemical compounds)  where analytical equipment sensitivity is limited by a  function, i.e. the  minimum y that can be measured depends on the magnitude of x. I'm trying to figure out what proportion of compounds can be measured by this method when I know distribution of x, y and the limiting  function.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $X$ has mean (standard deviation) $\mu_x$ ($\sigma_x$), and $Y$ has $\mu_y$ ($\sigma_x$) conditional on $X$ (*i.e.*, if you fix $X=x_0$, you get a specific $\mu_{y|x_0}$ and $\sigma_{y|x_0}$.  Further, assume that the $\mu_y$ depends on the $\mu_x$ via the function $y=f(x)$ and $\sigma_x$ via the function $y=g(x)$.

If there is some cut-off $c$, the proportions would be
$$P(Y < c | X=x) = P\left(Z < \frac{c-f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$$
That is, calculate the cut-off to a $z$-score using the formulas connecting the mean and standard deviation to the values of $x$.  Then, determine what proportion of the normal curve is below that $z$-score.